# Type 'NextApiRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'

Tags: typescript, session, next.js

The below code show an error in the Next.js project.

> Argument of type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
> Type 'NextApiRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 29 more.ts(2345)

```
import session from 'express-session'
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo'

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const MongoStore = connectMongo(session)


export default function sessionMiddleware(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, next: any) {
  const mongoStore = new MongoStore({
    client: req.dbClient,
    stringify: false,
  })

  return session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET ?? '',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: mongoStore,
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

[image]

Any solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote

My solution to the problem is using type union https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

```
import { RequestHandler, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

type NextApiRequestWithFormData = NextApiRequest &
  Request & {
    files: any[];
  };

type NextApiResponseCustom = NextApiResponse & Response;

export default function initMiddleware(middleware: RequestHandler) {
  return (
    req: NextApiRequestWithFormData,
    res: NextApiResponseCustom
  ): Promise<any> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      middleware(req, res, (result: any) => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
          return reject(result);
        }
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
}
```

the following code should work for you

```js
import { RequestHandler, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

type NextApiRequestWithFormData = NextApiRequest &
  Request & {
    files: any[];
  };

type NextApiResponseCustom = NextApiResponse & Response;
```